# .ajax to get back different values in different groups

Tags: jquery, split

now I'm sending an AJAX call using jQuery .ajax to a .php file that is getting all the values from the database, to process on it then send it back through different .ajax sent to different .php to update the database.

Now I'm doing this by getting all the data from the database then .split

```
    var result = data.split('&');
```

that's ok , but there is many different types of data that is hard to recognize on one group, is there a way to get more than one group of data for example like.

```
success: function(data,values) {
    var results = data.split('&');
    var allvalues = values.split('&');
```

because there is another problem that the number of certain groups of data is not fixed.
and this will be a problem when trying to select one value from all the values when they are all in one group.

I'm sorry I know I'm not so clear but this is the best I can do in explaining the problem, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better you can use `JSON datatype`

create json array at serverside

```
{"data":{"val1":"value","val2":"value"},"value":{"val1":"value","val2":"value"}}
```

There is a tutorial to understand JSON

http://secretgeek.net/json_3mins.asp

Then You can retrieve it simply

```
success:function(response){
response.data[0].val1
response.data[0].val2
response.value[0].val2
response.value[0].val2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out JSON datatype and send a array from php

```
success: function(json) {
    var results = json.data1.split('&');
    var allvalues = json.data2.split('&');
```